# ASP.NET Session Lost When Switching From HTTP to HTTPS Pages Using Load Balancing

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies, load-balancing, session-state

The Affinity for each server on load balancer is set to single and 95% of our users are not experiencing any problems at all.  However we do have users using Satellite/Proxies/Firewalls that when they hit our https page a new cookie is set and they lose their session.  As soon as they go back to an http page it's back though.  I have removed the web cluster environment and verified these users no longer experience this problem (so it's definitely related to the web cluster).  Like I said, this is mostly just affecting users that are using some sort of proxy and they claim no other sites give them issues.  Not sure what I can do as I've tried for a few days now to try and fix this issue. Any ideas, thoughts or advice would be greatly appreciated. Using .NET Framework 4.0 and Windows Network Load Balancing Manager

```
<sessionState cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" useHostingIdentity="true" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="***" timeout="10080" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this problem...I got this to work by going into IIS on each of the servers in the cluster and making the site ID and machine key the exact same.  The id of one site was set to 4 while another was set to 5.  This coupled with Generating a machine key on one of the servers and copying that exact key over to the other servers as well. Problem solved!